# ¿Se puede modificar un placeholder de un input por javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, javascript-objeto

Estando investigando para un proyecto quise modificar un placeholder por javascript dependiendo de la condicion, pero no e encontrado el como o si es posible el codigo que probe fue este sin resultados:
Codigo:

```
let placehold = document.getElementsByName("Topay");
    let valores = [12,24,36,60,120];
    if(select.selected[0]==true){

    placehold.values=toString(valores[0]);
}
```

y cuando lo cambio por getElementsById me dice que no es una funcion no se si ayude ese dato

Comment: por favor agrega tu HTML

Comment: por cierto, no es  `getElementsById` sino `getElementById` (sin la S)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ejemplo:

`document.getElementsByName('Topay')[0].placeholder = 'Nuevo texto';`

Adaptado el ejemplo que pusiste:

```
let placehold = document.getElementsByName('Topay')[0];
let valores = [12,24,36,60,120];
    
if (select.selected[0] == true) {
  placehold.placeholder = toString(valores[0]);
}
```